# how to bind in all frames

Tags: python, tkinter

I am doing a cube timer which start and stops by pressing the spacebar. This cube timer app has 2 types of timers, which are located at different frames.
The following code is a simplified version without including the widgets and functions.

```
class CubeTimerApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartOne, PageTwo, PageThree):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartOne)
    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.focus_set()
        frame.tkraise()
```

During the first frame I have

```
class StartOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, bg="green"):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        def button_startstop():
        ............

        self.bind("<space>", button_startstop)
```

For the seconds frame is

```
class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        def start start_stop():
        ...........

        self.bind("<Return>", start_stop())
```

When doing this, if I erease the bind line from the second frame, everything works fine. However, once I bind the seconds frame, it messes up with the interface and furthermore it doesn't work.

Bind all frames

Comment: I notice you are using pack manager for container and grid for contents, mixing managers is problematic, try using one or the other.

Comment: `self.bind("<Return>", start_stop())` will execute `start_stop()` immediately.  Change to `self.bind("<Return>", start_stop)` instead.

Comment: I have also used place for the different widgets in the frames. This could also lead to problems? Or is it only when you mix it with the same variable?

Comment: @Derek `pack` and `grid` cannot be used at the same time on widgets having same parent/master.  `container` and those frames do not have same parent/master, so it is ok.  @888888 `place` can be mixed with `pack` or `grid`.

Comment: @888888 Please don't put *"solved"* in your question.

Comment: Edit the question for the [mre] guide. And if you solved the question, why not answer your own question?